# In Haskell, if Maybe is a Type or an Union Type, how do you call `Nothing`?

Tags: haskell, union-types

In Haskell, a `Maybe` type can be either a `Nothing` or a `Just a`

```
data Maybe = Nothing | Just a
```

If we call `Maybe` Union Type, what is `Nothing` then? a `Type`? No, it's not a type, you can't declare a variable to be `Nothing` type.

Maybe you would say type constructor, true, but I want to express the fact that `Nothing` and `Just` are different cases.

a type value? a type instance? a type case?

Comment: It is a *data constructor*.

Comment: It is worth noting that the *type* constructor here is `Maybe` (as opposed to `Nothing` and `Just`).

Comment: `Maybe` is a type constructor... Give [this LYAH page](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#type-parameters) a read.

Comment: Keep in mind that when you see a declaration like e.g. `data T a = X a | Y Int | Z`, that `T` _only_ ever appears in type signatures, while `X`, `Y` and `Z` _only_ appear in code (i.e. at the term level). The syntax involves a lot of punning, and is quite confusing imo; e.g. `Y Int` in the declaration mixes type and term-level things in order to express "Y takes a single `Int`-type argument", yet in code it's used like `Y 42` or `Y (someNumber + 1)`. It's obviously never applied to a _type_

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is a [**data constructor**](https://wiki.haskell.org/Constructor#Data_constructor). Since it has no arguments, it is also called a **constant** and **nullary data constructor**.

These data constructors group values (well here there are no values) together, together with a *tag*: some sort of identifier that identifies that it is a `Nothing`, and not a `Just`.

Answer (score 4):

`Nothing` is also called a "case" of the "variant" (or "variant type") `Maybe a`. This terminology is used more frequently in OCaml than in Haskell, e.g., [Real World OCaml chapter of variants](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/variants.html) (I don't know what is common in other languages).